# Input's accept attribute doesn't recognise application/json?

Tags: html, json

I have an application that takes a file input from the user. One of the file types that it accepts is JSON.

File extensions in `input`'s `accept` are recognised fine in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept) (Safari being the main outlier), so sometimes the use of the MIME type is required. For JSON, the extension works fine, but if you use the [correct MIME type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), the input defaults to "All Files" as the filter.

```html
Extension (.json): <br>
<input type="file" accept=".json">

<br><br>

MIME type: (application/json): <br>
<input type="file" accept="application/json">
```

This only happens with JSON, for what I've been able to see. Why is that? Is the type not fully accepted yet? Is it a bug?

**Edit**:

Tested on:

```
                        | First | Second |
------------------------|-------|--------|
Windows 10/Chrome 61    |Success|  Fail  |
Windows 10/Firefox 56   |Success|Success |
OSX ElCapitan/Safari 9  | Fail  |Success |
Windows 10/Edge 40      |Success|  Fail  |
```

After seeing it work on Firefox, I'm starting to think it's a bug on Chrome.

Comment: How about a combination - `accept=".json,application/json"`, I wonder how does that behaves ?

Comment: @Teqchiqe Well, that will work on all browsers. But the question was why it doesn't work by itself. I think it's a bug.

Comment: This bug has long been fixed in Chrome.

Answer (score 48):

Please try this header:

`accept="application/JSON"`

It worked for me.